# Does Mongodb indexing make queries faster even if I just use a subset of indexed fields in query

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with records similar to the following:

```
{
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "NEW YORK",
  "state": "NY",
  "pop": 5574,
  "loc": [
    -74.016323,
    40.710537
  ]
}
```

If I create an index on city and state, how does it effect the following queries?

```
db.zipcode.find({city:"NEW YORK", "state": "NY","pop": 5574})

db.zipcode.find({city:"NEW YORK"})
```

Does it use the index at all? or the index will be only used if I query both city and state?

Comment: I could close this if the concept is understood but I am not a fan of people marking "duplicates" pointing to their own answer when there is very likely another duplicate question out there that actually explains it better. @Thilo You need to take note of this. So what does the poster have to say?

Comment: @NeilLunn what I got from Thilo answer in the other post is that in both cases index will be used. but I won't call this question a duplicate of that

Comment: The other question does answer this question, though vaguely because your question is vague. What is the actual index you make? Try your queries with .explain and you can see whether the indexes are used or not. Then read Thilo's old answer to understand when an index can be used and why.

Answer (score 1):

if you were to add .explain() at the end of the query, you will see exactly what query pan MongoDB executes to resolve your query.  In the examples you have provided, the index IS used.